# R: Repeated measures ANOVA with Pre and Post comparison

Tags: r, anova

I have a data frame, that looks something like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID condition side pre_1 pre_2 post_1 post_2
01 B left 13 11 77 80
01 C left 20 17 93 102
01 A left 9 13 60 58
01 C right 23 19 100 95
01 A right 11 11 70 77
01 B right 17 12 85 90
02 C left 18 12 79 85
02 A left 7 12 58 65
02 B left 12 10 79 85
02 A right 11 9 74 77
02 B right 15 9 90 85
02 C right 20 12 105 103', header=TRUE)
```

This is a within subject design. The experimental design was a repeated measure design were participants completed a task under 3 different conditions (A, B, C) and each condition on both sides of their visual field (side). Before and after each trial we conducted a physical measurement two times. The design was counterbalanced.

I would like to conduct the following analysis. A 3 (Condition: A-C) x 2 (Side: left/right) x 2 (Measure: Pre vs. Post) repeated measures ANOVA should be run.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you researched, and what have you tried? SO is no code writing service.